# Is there a way to prevent all the Docker containers within a service from auto restarting or starting automatically when Docker Desktop runs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I am currently using Docker Desktop.

However, I have built services using the `docker-compose up` command. I have noticed that whenever we start Docker Desktop, the containers attached to each service automatically starts. Is there a way to prevent this?

I know that it is possible to set the [restart policy](https://stackoverflow.com) of each container. But I don't know how to do this when there are multiple containers. Also multiple services may be using a container of the same name.

What I need is to prevent these services from starting and their containers.

Comment: Did you have all the services in one docker-compose file? For example Grafana,Loki and Nginx configuration all in one docker-compose yml ?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same docker file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of these commands to update your docker

`docker update --restart=no the-container-you-want-to-disable-restart`

`docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q)`

Comment: This seems like the correct answer

Comment: You can then go ahead and mark my answers as accepted.
Cheers

Comment: Is this also the way to prevent services from auto running?

Comment: This is just a way to prevent your containers from getting restarted each time you restart your docker Desktop